# jQuery AJAX Form does not return values

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have a multi-form app that gathers some information via AJAX and then allows the user to update that information and submit it again while continuing through the form.

The goal is to eliminate multiple pages to perform simple record updates.

My jQuery `.post()` returns the 'new' form with new values, but my second form does not submit the returned values, even the 'delete' returns either `object.HTMLElement` or `undefined`.

Please help, as I'm a jQuery newbie.

index.php

```
<form id="getCustomer">
    <select>
        <option value="1">John Doe</option>
        <option value="2">Jane Doe</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="customer_info">
    <form id="updateCustomer">
        <input type="text" name="firstName" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="lastName" value="" />
        <input type="submit" id="updateCustomer" value="Update" />
        <input type="submit" id="deleteCustomer" value="Delete" />
    </form>
</div>
<div id="info_status"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //AJAX selected customer
    $('#getCustomer').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
        $.post(
            'inc/getCust.inc.php',
            {id:id},
            function(output){
                $('#customer_info').html(output).show();
        });
    });
    //Prevent default form actions
    $('form').live('submit', function(){
        return false;// On submit return false
    });

    //AJAX Update Customer
    $('#updateCustomer').live('click', function(){
        var fname = $('input[name=firstName]').val();
        var lname = $('input[name=lastName]').val();
        $.post(
            'inc/updateCust.inc.php',
            { },
            function(output){
                $('#info_status').html(output).show();
        });
    });
    //AJAX Delete Customer
    $('#deleteCustomer').live('click', function(){
        var fname = $('input[name=firstName]').val();
        var lname = $('input[name=lastName]').val();
        var deleteCust = confirm('Delete: ' + c_fname + ' ' + c_lname + '?');
        if(deleteCust){
            $.post(
                'inc/deleteCust.inc.php',
                { id:id },
                function(output){
                    $('#info_status').html(output).show();
                }
            );
        }
    });
</script>
```

getCust.inc.php

```
<?php getCust($_POST['id']);?>
<form id="updateCustomer">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $CUST['fname'];?>" />
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="<?php echo $CUST['lname'];?>" />
    <input type="submit" id="updateCustomer" value="Update" />
    <input type="submit" id="deleteCustomer" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Comment: Part of your problem is that you have a function called `preCustData`, but you're calling it usng `prepCustData()` (pre -> prep)

Comment: Also, you're using `$CUST['fname']` for your lastName input. Maybe you mean `$CUST['lname']`?

Comment: Sorry I'm fixing the code, but getCust() just queries my database to fill in the known values... and it works fine.. I'm breaking at my prepCustdata() function and down...

Comment: So, I've replaced prepCust() with direct calls to the input values and now I get undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was unable to resolve the usage of `$('input[name=firstName]').val();`

However, after some modification `$('#firstName').val();` is working.

Final Working index.php code:

```
<form id="getCustomer">
    <select>
        <option value="1">John Doe</option>
        <option value="2">Jane Doe</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="customer_info">
    <form id="updateCustomer">
        <input type="text" id="firstName" value="" />
        <input type="text" id="lastName" value="" />
        <input type="submit" id="updateCustomer" value="Update" />
        <input type="submit" id="deleteCustomer" value="Delete" />
    </form>
</div>
<div id="info_status"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //AJAX selected customer
    $('#getCustomer').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
        $.post(
            'inc/getCust.inc.php',
            {id:id},
            function(output){
                $('#customer_info').html(output).show();
        });
    });
    //Prevent default form actions
    $('form').live('submit', function(){
        return false;// On submit return false
    });
    //AJAX Update Customer
    $('#updateCustomer').live('click', function(){
        var fname = $('#firstName').val();
        var lname = $('#lastName').val();
        $.post(
            'inc/updateCust.inc.php',
            { },
            function(output){
                $('#info_status').html(output).show();
        });
    });
    //AJAX Delete Customer
    $('#deleteCustomer').live('click', function(){
        var fname = $('#firstName').val();
        var lname = $('#lastName').val();
        var deleteCust = confirm('Delete: ' + fname + ' ' + lname + '?');
        if(deleteCust){
            $.post(
                'inc/deleteCust.inc.php',
                { id:id },
                function(output){
                    $('#info_status').html(output).show();
                }
            );
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is that you have a function called preCustData, but you're calling it usng prepCustData() (pre -> prep)

Another problem is that prepCustData isn't actually doing anything, just storing values in local variables that can't be accessed elsewhere. Try this instead:

```
function prepCustData(){
        var fname = $('input[name=firstName]').val();
        var lname = $('input[name=lastName]').val();
        return {f:fname,l:lname};
}
```

You can then access the data like this:

```
var data=prepCustData();
alert(data[f]);
alert(data[l]);
```

Another problem is that your code uses a variable called cid that doesn't seem to be calculated anywhere.

Comment: I'm extrapolating this code from a much larger group of variables, so the typos are mostly corracted now,  I'll try the return {}; on my main code

Comment: That's because you used `name=firstName` in the selector, but `id="firstName"` in the element.